# Emulator closes itself with 4 GB of RAM

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I have an `emulator` on `Android Studio` that closes itself changing the `RAM` setting  to 4GB, with 3GB works well.
This is the config I have right now:

[image]

If I set the `RAM` to 4 GB the emulator closes itself after being opened.

Here my system with the emualtor running wiht 3GB `RAM`:
[image]

Launching the emulator using the terminal I get this error:

> HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode. Failed to register
>   RAM block: va=0x7fff0000, size=0x100000000, method=legacy VCPU
>   shutdown request emulator: WARNING: Not saving state: emulator hasn't
>   finished booting. VCPU shutdown request

Any idea about how I can solve it?

Comment: How much RAM you have in your pc??

Comment: I have 8GB Intel i7

Answer (score 0):

The problem I had is that

> C:\YOUR_android_SDK_folder\extras\intel

was emphty, in others words `Haxm` was not installed.
If you have the same problem you have to go to:
 SDK manager -> SDK tools and check Intel Emulator accelerator